# java.net.ConnectException :connection timed out: connect?

Tags: java, networking, rmi, stub

I have used RMI in my code :

```
 import java.rmi.*;

 public interface AddServerIntf extends Remote {
  double add(double d1,double d2) throws RemoteException;
 }
```

---

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

public class AddServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements AddServerIntf {
  public AddServerImpl() throws RemoteException {
  }

 public double add(double d1,double d2) throws RemoteException {
  return d1+d2;
 }
}
```

---

```
import java.net.*;
import java.rmi.*;

public class AddServer {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
     AddServerImpl addServerImpl=new AddServerImpl();
     Naming.rebind("AddServer",addServerImpl);
    }  catch(Exception exc) {
          System.out.println(exc);
       }
   }
}
```

---

```
import java.rmi.*;
public class AddClient {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
     try {
       String Url="rmi://"+args[0]+"/AddServer";
       AddServerIntf addServerIntf=(AddServerIntf)Naming.lookup(Url);
       System.out.println("The first number is "+args[1]);
       double d1=Double.valueOf(args[1]).doubleValue();
       System.out.println("The second number is: "+args[2]);
       double d2=Double.valueOf(args[2]).doubleValue();
       System.out.println("The Sum is: "+addServerIntf.add(d1,d2));
     }  catch(Exception exc) {
         System.out.println(exc);
       }
   }
 }
```

These are 4 .java files written.

Next i compile all these files.Then I create a `stub` using `rmic AddServerImpl`.  After that i start rmi registry on server side using `start rmiregistry`. Then i start server using `java AddServer` and finally client using `java AddClient 27.60.200.80 5 9`.
*But nothing happens*

**Exception that is thrown on client side is `java.net.ConnectException : connection timed out : connect`**

What is the reason and how can i solve this?

On client machine these are the following .class files `AddClient.class AddServerImpl.class AddServerImpl_Stub.class` and on server side `AddServer.class AddServerImpl.class AddServerImpl_Stub.class AddServerIntf.class`

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception if any

Comment: Simplest explanation: your server's IP address is not what you think it is

Comment: The usual reason for this is solved by item A.1 in the RMI FAQ.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The error message says it all: your connection timed out. This means your request did not get a response within some (default) timeframe. The reasons that no response was received is likely to be one of:

- a) The IP/domain or port is incorrect
- b) The IP/domain or port (i.e service) is down
- c) The IP/domain is taking longer than your default timeout to respond
- d) You have a firewall that is blocking requests or responses on whatever port you are using
- e) You have a firewall that is blocking requests to that particular host
- f) Your internet access is down

Note that firewalls and port or IP blocking may be in place by your ISP

Comment: @ Richard of these i dont see any reason.

Comment: @Meprog - even though you don't see any reason, they're things that you should investigate and test, because they're the most likely reasons for a connection to time out. You should also take other peoples' advice and edit your post with the complete stack trace.

Comment: Neither (a) not (b) is correct. Both would produce 'connection refused'.

Comment: For java, use host = "localhost"

Comment: @shihab_returns Use it how? Where? Why? What are you talking about?

Comment: g) You live in a country that the US government has sanctioned.

Answer (score 1):

Number (1):  The IP was incorrect - is the correct answer.  The /etc/hosts file (a.k.a.
C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts ) had an incorrect entry for the local machine name.
Corrected the 'hosts' file and Camel runs very well.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: took me days of searching to find this, which answered a problem I was having with ehcache multicasting...isp had the wrong IP setup in the /etc/hosts file for the machine. Great insight!

Comment: In my case, the problem was that I had the same IP of the hots I was trying to connect to, in my IPv4. The network had automatically assigned me exactly the same IP.

Answer (score 0):

Exception : java.net.ConnectException

This means your request didn't getting response from server in stipulated time. And their are some reasons for this exception:

- Too many requests overloading the server
- Request packet loss because of wrong network configuration or line overload
- Sometimes firewall consume request packet before sever getting
- Also depends on thread connection pool configuration and current status of connection pool
- Response packet lost during transition

Answer (score -2):

If you're pointing the config at a domain (eg fabrikam.com), do an NSLOOKUP to ensure all the responding IPs are valid, and can be connected to on port 389:

```
NSLOOKUP fabrikam.com

Test-NetConnection <IP returned from NSLOOKUP> -port 389
```

Comment: Why? Port 389 is LDAP. This is Java RMI.