# not able to connect remote hiveserver2 using ip address

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am runnnig hive service hiveserver2 with following config in hive-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>hive.server2.thrift.bind.host</name>
<value>ip_address</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
<value>NONE</value>
</property>
```

From my local(same machine) jdbc client I am able to connect to hiveserver2

```
jdbc:hive2://id_address:10000/default
```

howerver when I run my jdbc client from other machine I am getting connection timeout issue.

Note that I am able to ping to hiveserver host with ip_address.

What could be issue? As I am using ip address still do I need to check entries in /etc/hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved

Issue was with firewall, hive configs were correct.

I disabled iptable for time being.

```
# services iptables stop
```

Following answer in following link was helpful for generic connection issues.

[java.net.ConnectException :connection timed out: connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662283/java-net-connectexception-connection-timed-out-connect)