# Java sockets, echo server

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to do a very basic echo server using java sockets, it works perfectly locally(running both the server and client on the same computer), when I try to run the client from another computer i get the exception :

```
Couldn't get I/O for the connection to XXX.XXX.XX.X
```

XXX.XXX.XX.X being the IP of the machine on which the server is running

btw : my code for both the server and the client is roughly that of the oracle beginner tutorials : 
  [server](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/EchoServer.java)
  [client](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/EchoClient.java)

EDIT : 
The full stacktrace I get :

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sockets.Client.main(Client.java:16)`

Comment: Is the port open and not blocked by a firewall?

Comment: Can you ping the server machine from the client machine at all?

Comment: I guess so since I used it to test locally? or no ??

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but i think that exception is thrown after the socket gets connected, when he tries to get the input and output stream. So the port should be open.

Comment: no it never gets to the  input and output stream ( just verified now)

Comment: You could print the stacktrace (inside the catch-block of the IOException) to get more details concerning the problem.

Comment: I just added the whole stacktrace

Comment: What port number do you specify on start?

Comment: I know it might sound obvious... but are you running the server before running the client?

Comment: yep the server is still running

Comment: can you show us the code of both client and server?

Comment: there is a link in the question, i use exactly the code of oracle except that I set the port number and ip adresse in the code instead of giving them to the main method via args

Comment: You could check the EchoServer without the EchoClient. Assuming that the EchoServer runs on the remote machine, you could use the telnet command instead of the EchoClient, i.e. `telnet remoteIp remotePort`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get the exception

```
    Couldn't get I/O for the connection to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

That is ***not*** an exception. It is a poorly designed error message that *conceals* the exception. When you get an exception, don't display/print/log a meaningless error message of your own devising. Display/print/log the *exception* itself, *and* its message, *and* its class, *and* its stacktrace.

> EDIT: The full stacktrace I get:

```
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Exactly. This is the *real* exception, and it almost certainly means there is a firewall preventing you from making the required connection.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the two used computers were hooked on two different wifi suppliers.
An [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662283/java-net-connectexception-connection-timed-out-connect) mentions possible other reasons.