# Generic exception:Connection timed out while using restTemplate

Tags: java, spring, api, resttemplate

I am curently trying to use this [public API](https://developers.wargaming.net/reference/):

Issue is that I get a timeout error but I haven't figured out why:

```
Generic exception: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/info/": Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

It's weird because if I just put [the request](https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/info/?application_id=74613ef82f2d90e9c88a8449723936fe&account_id=518913965&extra=statistics.random&fields=clan_id,client_language,created_at,global_rating,last_battle_time,updated_at) URL to my web browser, everything is returned properly.

So the question is: is this problem related to a misunderstanding of restTemplate or is there something missing in my request related to this API.

Here is my code:

```
public class PlayerWgApi {
    private final String apiUri = "https://api.worldoftanks.eu/";
    private final String moduleUri = "wot/";
    private final String applicationId = "74613ef82f2d90e9c88a8449723936fe";

    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> getVehicules(String accountId) {
        final String methodUri = "account/info/";
        final String uri = apiUri + moduleUri + methodUri;
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        UriComponents builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(uri)
                .queryParam("application_id", applicationId)
                .queryParam("account_id", accountId)
                .queryParam("extra", "statistics.random")
                .queryParam("fields", "clan_id,client_language,created_at,global_rating,last_battle_time,updated_at")
                .build();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);

        return restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, ApiResponse.class);
    }
}
```

And my ApiResponse class:

```
public class ApiResponse {
    String status;
    Meta meta;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private Map<String, PlayerResponse> player;

    getters/setters...
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code. It worked for me. If this is not complete code, check if you are setting request or read time outs.

Comment: Maybe you are behind a proxy. This proxy is set up in your browser, but not in your code ?

Comment: @Tristan, I don't use proxy, and I tested this on two different computers whithout any difference.

Comment: @Adi, I checked but I have nothing like that in my configurations.

Comment: @Synops As I said, it's working fine for me, although it's taking couple of seconds for response. See if this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662283/java-net-connectexception-connection-timed-out-connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly found why this is was not working, I was using my smartphone datas. There is no proxy configured on it anyway, so I still don't know what parameter is causing this issue. But when I switch to another network, everything is working properly.